# R: Conditional statement iterating over adjacent columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements, apply

Suppose I have the following `data.frame`:

```
>tmp

   user      start.date       X03.16.2013 X03.17.2013 X03.18.2013  X03.19.2013
   Allison   2013-03-15         5           5           0           2
   Andrew    2013-03-15         2           0           0           0
   Carl      2013-03-16         10          8           11          10
   Dora      2013-03-16         5           4           0           0
   Hilary    2013-03-17         NA          3           5           0
   Louis     2013-03-18         NA          NA          8           3
   Mary      2013-03-19         NA          NA          NA          7
   Mickey    2013-03-20         NA          NA          NA          NA
```

I would like to assign a "day of death" to users who have zero entries for two or more days. My approach was to run a loop over the columns and say "if the sum of `tmp[x,j:j+1]` is equal to zero then the `lastdateid` is `tmp[x,j]` for row `x`":

```
for (j in 3:dim(tmp)[2]){
  lastdateid <- apply(tmp, 1, function(x) {
    i <- which(sum(tmp[x,j:j+1])==0); ifelse(length(i), head(i,1), NA)
  })   
}
```

The above loop runs infinitely and also just creates the vector `lastdateid` full of `NA`s. Ideally the loop would return that Andrew's `lastdateid` is `tmp[2,4]` and Dora's is `tmp[4,5]` and everyone else has a value of `NA`. What is causing this loop to run infinitely? And how can I fix this statement st it gives the desired result? Please bear with me as I am relatively new to R. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could replace your `for` loop. It's a couple more lines but I'm sure it's more efficient.

```
w <- which(t(apply(tmp == 0, 1, cumsum)) == 2, arr.ind = TRUE)
w[,2] <- w[,2]-1 
rb <- rbind(w, matrix(, nrow(tmp)-nrow(w), ncol(w)))
rownames(rb) <- tmp$user[c(x <- w[,2], seq_len(nrow(tmp))[-x])]
```

Which gives the result

```
> rb
#         row col
# Andrew    2   4
# Dora      4   5
# Allison  NA  NA
# Carl     NA  NA
# Hilary   NA  NA
# Louis    NA  NA
# Mary     NA  NA
# Mickey   NA  NA
```

Comment: @ Richard Scriven Thank you for solution. As I am still new to using `which()` and `apply` in replacement of for loops I wondered if you could help me breakdown your first line. I know for `apply(tmp==0,1,cumsum)` it is saying apply the function `cumsum` over the rows of tmp (indicated by MARGIN=1) but I'm uncertain as to how `which()` knows to run cumsum over two adjacent columns (in the future I want to be able to choose how many adjacent cell to sum over).

Comment: @JMeo Sure.  `tmp == 0` turns the original data into a logical matrix.  `t(apply(tmp == 0, 1, cumsum)` runs `cumsum` through the rows, and `== 2` is used to find where the second occurrence of zero occurred.  Wrapping that with `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)` tells us the matrix row and column indices where that second occurrence of zero is.

Comment: @ Richard Scriven  Thank you for taking the time to run through this for me. I'm still learning how to most effectively use `apply()` and `which()` in place of loops. Very helpful!